# Try catch doesn't work for 414 error on image tag

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I cannot handle the 414 error coming from image tag src on javascript with following code,

```
try {
new Image().src=`https://z.com?x=asdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsdasdasdasdsdasdsdasdsd`;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('414 err');
}
```

any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onerror` property instead.

```js
let img = new Image;
img.onerror = function() {
    // handle error
}
img.src = '...';
```